# Bootstrap css grid with Prime-ng

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use grid from Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/ and also have elements from prime-ng (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/). Is it possible to mix it ? I am novice in front end stuff. Thanks for answers.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095217/primeng-with-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it - it is possible to combine them. In particular, it is possible to use the Bootstrap grid system with GUI elements from PrimeNG.

Note however that PrimeNG also comes with a responsive grid system (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/responsive), though the Bootstrap principles seem more powerful and are certainly more widely in use (hardly surprising, given that PrimeNG is quite new). Nonetheless - if the PrimeNG possibilities are enough for your needs, you may want to check if you really need both in your project.